# How to change degree of a clock hand on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, math

I have implemented an analog clock with the logic:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="clock">
        <div class="clock-face">
            <div class="hand hand-hour"></div>
            <div class="hand hand-minute"></div>
            <div class="hand hand-seconds"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    const minuteHand = document.querySelector('.hand-minute');
    const secondHand = document.querySelector('.hand-seconds');


    function getTime() {
        const now = new Date();

        const seconds = now.getSeconds();
        const secondsDegree = (((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90);
        secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegree}deg)`


        const minutes = now.getMinutes();
        const minutesDegree = (((minutes / 60) * 360) + 90);
        minuteHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesDegree}deg)`


        const hours = now.getHours();
        const hoursDegree = (((hours / 60) * 360) + 90);
        hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hoursDegree}deg)`



    }

    setInterval(getTime, 1000);
```

**CSS**

```
.clock-face {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        transform: translateY(-3px);
    }

    .hand {
        width: 50%;
        height: 6px;
        background: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform-origin: 100%;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

It works perfectly, wondering how I can change the degree of hour hand of this clock depending on clientX and clientY on **mouse click**.

I know I need to calculate the angle between clicked spot and the current position of hour hand and rotate it as much as needed, of course the interval must change somehow to be match with the new time.

Comment: Show a [example]. External link is insufficient.

Comment: There is code in the provided link that does exactly what you are asking about. Look for: "_And finally, the meat of the tutorial, our Javascript Code will look like this:_"

Comment: @RandyCasburn I think my explanation was kind of ambiguous. I tried to clarify it. would you mind checking it out ?

Comment: the angle bit is pretty easy ([Math.atan2()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2), coordinates are easy to get using [.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) on the `clock-face` element. This is your challenge: "_the interval must change somehow to be match with the new time._" each interval creates a new Date object with a new time. That instantiation will need to relay on the previous iteration with seconds updated to the new seconds. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I could solve this problem for calculating the new degree for the second hand :

```
const rect = clock.getClientRects()[0];
const clockCenter = {
    y: rect.bottom - ((rect.bottom - rect.top) / 2),
    x: rect.right - ((rect.right - rect.left) / 2)
}
let newSecond = Math.atan2(clockCenter.y - e.y, clockCenter.x - e.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Comment: of course you need to change the settimeout stuff for the new time of other hands.